# Dart VM embedding (libdart_jit.a) on MacOS produces "dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN4dart13FLAG_profilerE"

Tags: macos, dart, clang++

I am trying to make my first C++ app with embedded Dart VM. I have a problem with minimal setup of compiler on my MacOS 10.14.6. My build is successful, but when I start the app, it crashed with:

```
$ clang++ -I ${HOME}/opt/dart-sdk --define-macro DART_SHARED_LIB=1 -L ./libs/debug -ldart_jit -lm -lz -O2 -undefined dynamic_lookup -o reproduce *.cpp
$ ./reproduce
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN4dart13FLAG_profilerE
```

Although symbol `__ZN4dart13FLAG_profilerE` presents inside binary

```
$ nm reproduce | grep __ZN4dart13FLAG_profilerE
                 U __ZN4dart13FLAG_profilerE
```

How to compile/link this properly?

My reproduce program is:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <include/dart_api.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char* setVMFlagsError = Dart_SetVMFlags(argc, argv);
    if (setVMFlagsError != nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Error while set Dart VM flags: " << setVMFlagsError << "\n";
        ::free(setVMFlagsError);
        return 1;
    } else {

        Dart_InitializeParams params = {};

        std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Dart SDK was built following by official [documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building)

```
(dart-sdk-pyenv)  ~/tmp/dart-sdk/sdk $ ./tools/build.py --mode all --arch x64 create_sdk
(dart-sdk-pyenv)  ~/tmp/dart-sdk/sdk $ cp -a ~/tmp/dart-sdk/sdk/xcodebuild/DebugX64/dart-sdk ~/opt/
```